# Slack MultiExternalSelectElement block suggestion handler taking 30 sec to respond (Slack SDK for Java)

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands, slack-dialog, slack-bolt

I am using external multi select in a modal. Calling BlockSuggestionHandler when user enters some characters and calling external api in this handler with each user interaction. But the response from external api and conversion to List is taking approx 30 sec. Hence getting **"Nothing could be found"** in the dropdown.

- Tried checking response_url but it is null for this block interaction and as per slack docs response_url in modals is only available on submission.
- Also tried to use views.update api with the list of options fetched from api call but for external multi select, we do not have options where i can set the list.
  Please suggest some way out for this external multi select.